# error al querer mostrar resultados de base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

al querer mostrar el resultado de una aconsulta a mi bases de datos me tirar error

este es el codigo donde lista el menu

```
<?php

            $mk = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT DISTINCT genero FROM img");

            while ($m = mysqli_fetch_array($mk)) {
                echo "<a href=genero.php?genero=".$m['genero']."><kbd>".$m['genero']."</a><kbd><br>";

            };
            ?>
```

y en la pagina genero.php tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<?php

include('hola.php');

$genero = $_GET['genero'];


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slide.css">
    <title>bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">.
                <h1 class="border">PiratyLandia</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2 border">
                <!--<?php

                $mk = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT DISTINCT genero FROM img");

                while ($m = mysqli_fetch_array($mk)) {
                    echo "<kbd>".$m['genero']."<kbd><br>";

                };
                ?>-->
            </div>
            <div class="col ">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php
                    echo $genero;
                    $data = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT * FROM img WHERE genero=$genero");

                    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                        echo"<div class=col-3 card bg-danger ><img src=img/".$d['imagen']."><p class=text-capitalize text-center>".$d['titulo']."<br>(".$d['anio'].")</p></div>";

                    };
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Si utilizamos componentes de Bootstrap que requieran Javascript agregar estos tres archivos -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

en vez de mostrarme todos los resultados que hay con el where genero=$genero, 
 me tira el siguiente error

> Warning
>   : mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyects\prove\genero.php
>   on line
>   46

no le encuentro la manera, y veo que el dato si lo toma desde el listados de generos de la pagina anterior

Comment: El error porque `mysqli_query` retorna falso, si `$genero` es una cadena debería ir entre comillas, `"SELECT * FROM img WHERE genero='$genero'"` , es la solución, pero lo recomendable es utilizar sentencias preparadas ;)

Answer (score 0):

el problemas creo que es que estas usando mysqli_fetch_array con un solo parametro, este usa dos parametros y estas colocando solo uno. cambia eso.

si por ejemplo $c es tu conexion intenta con algo asi aunque no veo el resto de tu codigo pero para que tengas idea:

```
$c = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','clientes');

    $consulta = mysqli_query($c,'SELECT DISTINCT genero FROM img');
    while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

No se si te funcione exactamente, pero ya sabes cual es el problema. Espero ser de ayuda.

Comment: Hola Henry gracias por contribuir pero para la función `mysqli_fetch_array` el segundo parámetro es **opcional**, ese no es la causa del error.

Comment: Cieeerto, tienes razón ya vi el error que indicaste, muy acertado.. Gracias.